# Handling promise and async await function

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, async-await, es6-promise

I have this function in node and express

```
router.post('/', async (req, res) => {
    const playlist = new Playlist({
        song: req.body.song,
        artist: req.body.artist
    })

    try {
        const newPlaylist = await playlist.save()
        res.status(201).json(newPlaylist)
    } catch (err) {
        res.status(400).json({ message: err.message })
    }
})
```

However, I am getting this error

```
(node:23242) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'song' of undefined
```

Comment: I think you'll have to show us the code for `playlist.save()` and for the `Playlist()` constructor because there's nothing obvious in the code you have shown that would cause that error.

Comment: It's hard to know without seing more of your code, but either new Playlist() is a Promise under the hood, or playlist.save() is doing something funky. I'd suggest adding console logs and seeing which one of those two things is actually failing

Comment: .save is a mongoose method @jfriend00

Comment: Yeah, but isn't there some model code somewhere of yours involved in the `.save()` process?  Because the code you've shown here will not cause `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning` by itself.  So, something ELSE must be contributing.  It's also possible that `new Playlist()` is throwing and that gets reported as an `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning` because it's in an `async` function.

Comment: The error doesn't give you any more specifics, like the error message and which line number the error is on?

Comment: find every `Promise` and add `catch` for it.

Comment: I suspect you're getting something like "cannot access property `song` of undefined" or something like that. If the code before the try/catch throws an error, it'll turn into a rejected Promise, which you're not currently handling.

Comment: @Jacob thats exactly what I am getting TypeError: Cannot read property 'song' of undefined

Comment: Instead of manual try/catch (which might not cover enough, or might throw in the catch part), consider a router that can handle promises, like [express-promise-router](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-promise-router).

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the full error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend you also wrap that first part in a try/catch. If `req.body` somehow doesn't get populated, or if `new Playlist` throws any sort of error, since this is an async function, that'll become a rejected Promise. This is safer:

```
router.post('/', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const playlist = new Playlist({
            song: req.body.song,
            artist: req.body.artist
        })
        const newPlaylist = await playlist.save()
        res.status(201).json(newPlaylist)
    } catch (err) {
        res.status(400).json({ message: err.message })
    }
})
```

If you're getting a "Cannot read property 'song' of undefined" error, that means that the request body could not be parsed and remains `undefined`. Maybe the wrong `content-type` header was sent or you don't have a body parsing middleware set up correctly.

Comment: Thanks I dont get the error anymore which is great. But when I make a post request using Postman, I get this error {
    "message": "Cannot read property 'song' of undefined"
}. So maybe I probably didnt set up the body parsing properly

Comment: Is this supposed to process JSON? If so, is postman sending `content-type: application/json`? Is express configured to parse JSON?

Comment: If you haven't set up your body parsing middleware, see https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser

Comment: I read somewhere that express now comes with the body parser, so I didnt install the body parser separately. I will try that now.

Answer (score 0):

You have handled the exception using try ... catch and this is great.
Although outside of this `try catch` can be an issue.
So there might to be two errors here

1. Either `req.body.song` or `req.body.artist` OR `Playlist` is not a valid class
2. On your catch block `res.status(400).json({ message: err.message })` this could be another issue.

It would be great if you try and catch entire code block and log the err and it would be clear.

`UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning` is happened because you didn't catch the exception.